# With a D-Visa, may I enter the Schengen area through a different country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, transit-visas, airport-transfer, long-stay-visas

I have a Netherlands MVV valid for 90 days and I have few repatriation flights from India to Paris or Frankfurt. Is it possible for me to complete my immigration at Frankfurt/Paris and then do a self check in for new flight or train towards the Netherlands.

Is possible to have my arrival port of immigration at a different destination in the Schengen area other than the Netherlands?

Answer (score 12):

There are several things to consider.

- **Regular Schengen rules:** No problem entering the area through another country than the Netherlands, your Dutch MVV allows and will be recognized (for this purpose) in other Schengen countries.
- **Covid-19 related restrictions on entry:** The EU made some recommendations regarding entry in the Schengen area from outside the union, which are roughly followed by France and [Germany](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/EN/2020/03/corona-ein-und-ausreise-en.html). Under those rules, third-country citizens are banned from entering the area but there is an exception for those with a long-stay visa transiting to their country of residence. For Germany, there is an additional stipulation that transits must be unavoidable (“if no other travel connection is possible”). I think other countries have at times been more restrictive and effectively banned entry, even for transit so you need to check what the exact rules are before choosing an airport.
- **Covid-19 related restrictions on moving through the country:** Long-distance (more than 100km) travel in France is still severely restricted. You need to fill in another self-declaration form for that. While the form for entry into the country mention EU residence as an exception, the form regarding movements inside the country requires a specific purpose. The government has remained critical of travels to switch residences and that purpose is *not* listed on the form.

  Consequently, I am pretty sure it should be possible to catch another plane at the airport but I am not sure the police would look favorably to you going by road to the center of Paris to connect to another means of transportation.
- **Transportation availability:** You cannot rely on all the usual connections being available. Last I check there were one or two flights a day from Paris Charles-de-Gaulle to Amsterdam but Thalys traffic is still effectively interrupted (only one train a day from central Paris to Brussels with no direct stop at CDG and no connection to the Thalys to Amsterdam, severe restrictions on transit on the Belgian side). Direct train service is planned to resume in about two weeks. Paris-Orly is entirely closed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.  There is no requirement to enter the Schengen area through any particular country or port of entry.